# Boost recent item in MoreLikeThis Solr request handler

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I want to boost my MoreLikeThis results depending on there Creation date (desc) the url I'm using is

http://localhost:9090/solr/core0/select/?q=power&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on&mlt=true&mlt.fl=title,body&fl=content_id,title,seourl,cdate&mlt.count=5

But the results I get from this url are like

1. when q=power, and if the result is of the year say 2008, then I get MorelikeThis results for power only but for the year 2008 and it does not gives me the recent similar results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, that MLT is usable? 
Look, if the termVector is activated for your (default) query field. Look for `termVectors="true"` in the schema.xml and set, if it is not.

look at this: -> http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis#TermVectors.2C_Analyzers_and_MoreLikeThis

By the way: your URL does not boost anything.

For boosting look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents

Comment: And how does this boost the MLT results? Is boosting or sorting of MLT results even possible?

Answer (score 0):

> For boosting look at this: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents

SolrRelevancy functions can be used only with SearchHandler, I don't know any way to use relevance/boosting functions with other handlers.